# Can SharePoint's Select People and Groups dialog box's Title and Department fields be customized with a custom membership provider?

Tags: sharepoint, membership-provider

I have created a custom membership provider for a SharePoint application but would like to populate the Title and Department columns for the MembershipUsers that are displayed with data from my user repository.

Is this possible? How can it be done?

I don't see anything in the System.Web.Security.MembershipUser class that could store this information. How does the Windows AD MembershipProvider have a different Display Name than the Account Name? Are some of these values coming from someplace else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens in the AD is that, SharePoint runs the User Profile Sync Job that will pull all the required information from AD and updated the SharePoint UserProfile DB which In turn pushes to Each of the Site. Whereas in the case of the Custom Membership we don't have a direct option to update the Profile Information.

One method you can do is to update those information using code.There are two options you can update the User Profile information in the SSP so that it will be displayed in all the Site Collection or to Update the **SPWeb.SiteUserInfo** List. Please refer these [link1](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2007-1-SharePoint_2007_Utility_-2_-_PI_-_Utility_to_Import-Export_actual_user_profiles.aspx) , [link2](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/justguy/archive/2008/08/01/fba-in-sharepoint-everything-you-ve-ever-wanted-to-do-continued.aspx) on how to do that. In case you want to update in **SiteUserInfo** list it is just another list just search for Item based on the user account  name and update that item.